# Proving the norm expression using Neumann expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometric-series, matrix-norms

I have been trying to solve the problem, but wasn't able to move after applying Neumann expansion. The square matrix F satisfies $||F||<1$.

I am trying to show the following.

$$
||(I-F)^{-1}|| \le \frac{1}{1-||F||}
$$

I think I could convert the term in the left to the following given $||F||$ is a scalar. Using the geometric series:
$$
||\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}F^{i}|| \le 1+||F||+||F^{2}||+...+||F^{k}||= \frac{1}{1 - ||F||}
$$
$$
||\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}F^{i}|| \le \frac{1}{1 - ||F||}
$$

Can I make the reasoning above?

Comment: You need to make the further observation that $\|F^k\| \leq \|F\|^k$; note that the two are not necessarily equal

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks! Totally forgot about it. After that, will the inequality check out?

Comment: Yes it will${}{}{}$